# Error Go Function When I want to return file type

Tags: go

I am new to Go, i want to create a function that return a file type.

```
func createFile(filename string) (*File, error) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    return f, err
}
```

But when, i run this code the compiler says undefined File

Comment: Such fundamental basics are covered very well in the Tour of Go: Work through it ince more.

Answer (score 3):

`File` type is in `os` package so you really want your function to return `(*os.File, error)`.

Answer (score 1):

May be this not related directly to your situation, using this we can pick/sort/filter based on file extensions. this code, at-present extract `.jpg/.jpeg` extension files

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {

    filepath.Walk("../searchStartFromWhere/", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        ext := filepath.Ext(path)
        switch ext {
        case ".jpg", ".jpeg": // Add more switch cases if required 
            fmt.Println(path)
        }
        return nil
    })
}
```